# В чем смысл использовать Lazy в данном случае?

Tags: c#

В проекте нашел следующее:

```
public partial class IdentifierLogic                                          
    : BaseEntityLogic<Identifier>                                             
{                                                                                                                                                      
    private readonly Lazy<AccessControlListLogic> _accessControlListService = 
        new( () => new AccessControlListLogic() );                            
                                                                              
    private readonly SystemLogic _systemLogic;                                
    private readonly Channel<AclEvent> _eventEmitter;                         
                                                                              
    public IdentifierLogic(                                                   
        ISegmentDbContextFactory dbContextFactory,                            
        Channel<AclEvent> eventEmitter )                                      
        : base( dbContextFactory )                                            
    {                                                                         
        _systemLogic = new SystemLogic( dbContextFactory );                   
        _eventEmitter = eventEmitter;                                         
    }
```

У меня вопрос: почему тут используется Lazy, когда этого можно не делать, как мне кажется. Сервис стартует и работает все время жизни, поэтому можно считать, что Lazy всегда тоже будет инициализирован. И никакого выигрыша в производительности, я тут, если честно, не вижу

Comment: Lazy существует не для выигрыша в производительности, это отложенная инициализация. Зачем она здесь вам никто не скажет, так как примера, что вы привели, недостаточно чтобы понять зачем вообще этот класс и его поля существуют и в чем их смысл.

Comment: В моем понимании, этого кода должно быть достаточно, но хорошо, я постараюсь дополнить. А отложенная инициализация - это ведь и есть выигрыш в производительности. Или что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: отложенная инициализация - это про экономию ресурсов. Например, если кнопка на форме требует каких то тяжелых вычислений, то проще эти вычисления сделать, когда на кнопку нажмут, чем вычилсть все заранее, ведь кнопку могут и не нажать, и тогда вычисления заранее будут потерей времени. То есть если что то требует значительных затрат - то лучше это запустить по мере необходимости. Так и Lazy - он не будет ничего созавать, пока к нему не обратишься, а вот если обратишься, он создаст класс один раз и в следующий раз ты уже будешь обращаться к созданному классу.

Comment: ааа, все, теперь я точно понимаю, как оно работает, спасибо!

Comment: тогда преимущества в Lazy в данном месте нет - система будет работать месяцами. Приложение у нас стартует и так долго, конструктор у этого класса дефолтный (никакой сложной работы в нем нет), поэтому ждать на старте минуту или 61 секунду-не так важно, когда система будет работать месяцами. А lazy будет выполняться при первом обращении, грубо, это будет в первые несколько часов и дальше месяцами оно так и будет работать